# How to log to a file in Redux?

Tags: redux, react-redux

Is there any simple way how to log actions and states from Redux to a file? I found this awesome logger https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger, but it seems to be used only for logging to console.

Answer (score 3):

You can't simply log to a file since your application is executed by the browser. If you want to export logs to a log file, you have to add some mechanism to send back this information to server. Then server will be able to put this infos in a file.

Answer (score 3):

1. Decorate your logger to intercept any log
2. store any log to a state
3. `JSON.stringify` your state
4. create `ObjectURL` from your state. ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL))
5. Download it from `<a download="logs.json" src="${objecturl}" />`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like redux-logger accepts a [`logger`](https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger#logger-object) parameter where you can specify your own console implementation.